# SFML/C++/Windows10 weird message?

Tags: c++, windows, sfml

I'm programming using SFML and C++. I've never had an issue but now I'm getting some gray box popping up about "Game bar" and other things. What is this? I have no idea what it is and why it started happening.

[image]

Comment: have you tried checking the `don't show again` check box... ?

Comment: Yeah, it only disables it for the program's life time. The next time the program start's it appears again. I'm wondering why this is only happening in SFML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a built-in feature of Windows 10, when it sees an app as a game it get triggered automaticallly, but it can also be enabled intentionally... or by accident.

Whenever you press `WINDOWS KEY + G`, the bar apears asking if you want to open this as a game:
[image: Trigger action]

If you tick on that box, then Windows will register the executable as a game and then, every time it starts it will display that bar.

I found no global switch to disable it, but on each app you make you can always manually edit the settings:

[image: Settings]

When the misbehaving app starts, press `WINDOWS KEY + G` on the keyboard. The click on the settings panel. On the first tab at the bottom you have to untick the option that says something like **Save this as a game**. After that, the app will no longer appear as a game and wil no show the bar.

To enable it again in case you want it, press the key combo again and tick on open this as a game. Done!

Comment: The application isn't fullscreen. I just cropped the original image because it contained other parts of my desktop. What is shown there is directly the window without title bar. It's a 800x600 pixel window. Also, I don't have an Xbox controlled connected.

Comment: Perhaps Windows identified SFML's DLL as a game, perhaps you can disable the Xbox bar on the Xbox app settings if you don't like it appearing. Having or not an Xbox controller doesn't affect it appearing. Not sure however the steps to disable it on Xbox settings

Comment: Where can I find the Xbox settings on Windows 10? I've looked in the settings app.

Comment: Let me edit the answer, I found the way you accidentally enabled it and how to reverse it. Hang on a moment... Edit, might just do a new answer, Its a better plan

Comment: Thanks, I accepted the answer though I'd appreciate it if you submitted a new answer, for people looking at my comments they make no sense.

Comment: Don't worry about that, those interested will probably look at the chance log of this answer to see previous incarnations of the answers.